# Remove `class="dno"` from the "hide ignored tags" div in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, design, ignored-tags

Ever briefly see an interesting question, but it disappears because it has an ignored tag on it?

You end up searching for it, then sorting by *newest*, to try to find it again.

As it turns out, there is **already** an option to unhide ignored tags, right from any page:

```
<div class="dno">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hideIgnored" title="hide ignored tags" checked="checked"><label for="hideIgnored"> hide ignored tags</label>
</div>
```

But `.dno` in [all.css](https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css) is defined as `.dno{display:none;}`.

Removing the `class` from the `div` gives you the option, underneath your list of ignored tags:

> [image]

Comment: Retagging this as feature request - it was intentionally removed and is not a bug.

Comment: @NickCraver Out of interest, may I ask why it was removed?